# Save cx_freeze errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

So when a python program has been frozen using cx_freeze it opens up an alert whenever the program crashes the only problem is the only way to distribute the traceback (for bug reports) is by screenshot-ting the alert box which is a bit of a pain (you can't copy text from the alert box).

Is there any way to save cx_freeze error reports? For example by writing them into a crash-log file. It seams a shame to present the crashes in such a helpful way and yet have no way of easily sending crash reports to developers (screenshot-ting being a but tedious).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is actually possible to copy the text from a Windows message box, but I agree that it's not obvious to users that you can do that.

It should be possible to set [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys#sys.excepthook) to a function that saves the error and traceback somewhere. This will stop cx_Freeze displaying the error message box, so it's up to you to notify the user about errors if that's appropriate.

Comment: an excellent answer - I agree with the theory and will test then comment with the results